# Pattern Recognizing in Integrals and Probability Distirbutions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is a basic pattern recognizing question to begin with, but asks about probability densities.

Solve the following integrals and find a pattern. I was able to solve them all and they are all equal. Observe, $$\int^1_0 {4\choose1}x(1-x)^3dx=\int^1_0{4\choose2}x^2(1-x)^2\,dx=\int^1_0{4\choose3}x^3(1-x)\,dx=.2.$$
Based on that I thought okay so we essentially have 
$$\int^1_0{n\choose a}x^a(1-x)^{n-a}\,dx$$
The question states, verify your conjecture for $$\int^1_0 {6\choose 4}x^4(1-x)^2 \,dx=\frac{1}{7}$$
I believe that a possible conjecture for the answer is $\frac{1}{n+1}$

The next part of the question is use this pattern to find the value of $c$ such that $X$~$f(x)=cx^k(1-x)^{n-k}$ for $x\in [0,1]$ is a probability density.  I determined that $c=$$n \choose a$$n+1$. 
Find the Expected Value and Variance. I know now what $c$ is but in setting up the expected value aspect and variance is too general. How can one solve the integral of $x^{k+1}(1-x)^{n-k}$

Lastly, A number Q is chosen at random which is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Then a coin with prob $Q$ of getting a head is flipped $n$ times. Let $A$ be the number of heads and compute $P(A=k)$. I simply do not understand what is going on here for this last one.

Comment: You may want to edit for the following: The value that all of your first three integrals evaluates to is $1/5 = 0.2$, not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the first part.  For the second part, they are looking for an expression for $c$ such that

$$
\int_{x=0}^{1} cx^k(1-x)^{n-k} \, dx = 1
$$

If you try $c = \frac{1}{2(n+1)}$, you will see that this does not work.  Based on the expressions in the first part, what can you substitute for $c$ that does work?

The third part is answered by the first two parts, actually, including your conjectured value.

Comment: dont you mean the integral?

Comment: Are you talking about the second part or the third part?

Comment: the second part. because the shouldn't the prob under the distribution of the entire part be equal to 1?

Comment: Hmm, it's possible I misinterpreted that.  Let me go back for a moment...OK, you're right, I fixed it.  But your proposed value for $c$ still seems wrong.

Comment: c is always $n \choose k$

Comment: Not quite.  If $c = \binom{n}{k}$, then your integrals in the first part would have evaluated to $1$, but they don't.

Comment: then I do not see what substitute for c will work

Comment: You're very close.  Setting $c = \binom{n}{k}$ made the integral evaluate to $1/(n+1)$.  How much would you have to scale $c$ up to make the integral evaluate to $1$?

Comment: n+1. Did you want to go to chat?

Comment: No, I think you've got the right answer now.  Double check with some explicit examples.

Comment: edited. So $c=$$n choose k$$n+1$. But I think the expected value is too hard to solve then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23555/discussion-between-brian-tung-and-jack-armstrong).